# how are DNS servers selected in system-resolved?

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved

The man page of `resolved.conf` for system-resolved states that if `DNS=` is set, "DNS requests are sent to one of the listed DNS servers".

How is that server selected? Is that a round-robin? a random choice? the fastest server is selected? other?

Answer (score 0):

List order, and 5 (default) seconds timeout before trying next one.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf

Comment: That's for the GLibC resolver. Is that the same for system-resolved?

Comment: In theory yes, but systemd resolved keeps track of dns that failed to resolve, so it may happen (and happens) that requests goes straight to 2nd nameserver if 1st failed before.